# Preserve a string that looks like date as text when printing to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some values that looks like this:

```
    A
1   DEC 2018
2   NOV 2018
3   OCT 2018
4   SEP 2018
5   Q119 SGX
6   Q120 SGX
7   Q219 SGX
```

The top 4 are in string format.

However, when I store them in an array using VBA and output them into cells again, my output looks like this:

```
    A
1   Dec-18
2   Nov-18
3   Oct-18
4   Sep-18
5   Q119 SGX
6   Q120 SGX
7   Q219 SGX
```

I've tried `Dim arrOuput() as String` but Excel seems to automatically convert any string that looks like date into actual date format anyways. Is there some way I preserve the values just as text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate it with `'` just as you would in GUI.

```
Sub preserveStringFormat()

    Dim strDate As String

    strDate = "DEC 2018"

    range("A1").Value = "'" & strDate

    MsgBox "alright!"

End Sub
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Set the destination number format to Text (e.g. `"@"` before dropping the values back onto the worksheet.

```
    With Worksheets("sheet7")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            Debug.Print .Address(0, 0)
            .Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
            .Offset(0, 1) = .Value2
        End With
    End With
```